# How to prevent my Timer from GC collecting before its callback excuted?

Tags: c#

I need to create a bunch of timer as local variable to do something like:

```
void Foo()
{
    Timer t = new Timer(myTimerCallback,null,1000,Timeout.Infinite);
}
```

Unfortunately, some of them are collected by GC before them invoke myTimerCallback after 1 second. Since I have so many Timers, it's impossible to store them in private static member. And it's also hard to find a place to put GC.Keeplive(t).

How can I make each timer to do their thing before dying?

Comment: The reason why I don't want to store these timer in a private member is there are too many. I can try it but is there any better way?

Comment: If there are too many timers to store, maybe it's time to take a step back and ask yourself whether you're solving the right problem?

Comment: seconding @damien's comment.  You shouldn't fight the GC in a managed runtime.  I'd suggest biting the bullet and storing the references.  You might be surprised at how little impact it has on performance.

Comment: @Renze-de-waal, @Sean, @hans-passant, @okutane I learned today that the [public Timer(TimerCallback callback)](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/timer.cs,919) uses `this` for `state` and will survive garbage collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store them in a collection to keep a reference and in the event method remove the reference from the collection. I think you need to use the state parameter to identify the timer in the collection (pass a reference to the timer or a key in the collection as state parameter in the "new timer"  statement).

Please note that the callback functions are executed on other threads, so you will/may have multiple callback functions running simultaneously. Use locking to ensure that adding/removing references is done safely.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is to store them in a member variable and then dispose of them when you no longer need them.

Answer (score 1):

Store them in a member, for example a `List<Timer>`.

Answer (score 1):

Why it's impossible to store them? Maybe you can just remove them from that collection when their work is done?

Answer (score 1):

It's important to see that GC.KeepAlive() cannot solve your problem.  That just extends the lifetime of your object to the statement.  You would have to loop or block for as long as the timer needs to stay alive.  Also beware that the life time of references in local variables is different in the Debug build.  The JIT keeps them life until the end of the method to allow watches to work.  Producing tricky "works in debug, doesn't work in release mode" problems.

You'll have to keep a life reference to the timer object.  That's most typically done with a field in a class.  Lifetime requirements now pass to the class object, it needs to stay alive for as long as the timer is needed.  Not usually a problem.  If it is, you'll have to make the reference static.

Answer (score 0):

## A. System.Threading vs System.Timers

It's worth pointing out that the keeping reference issue is specific to `System.Threading.Timer` and not `System.Timers.Timer`.

---

## B. Threading.Timer's Timer(TimerCallback callback) constructor

This is not a solution to your problem but I think it's still relevant to the topic.

`System.Threading.Timer`'s `Timer(TimerCallback callback)` constructor (the one that doesn't take the `dueTime` and others) uses `this` for `state` which means that the timer will keep a reference to itself and this means that it will survive garbage collection.

```
public Timer(TimerCallback callback)
{
    (...)
    TimerSetup(callback, this, (UInt32)dueTime, (UInt32)period, ref stackMark);
}
```

### Example

Timer 'C' is created using `Timer(TimerCallback callback)` and it just keeps going after `GC.Collect()`.

#### Output

```
A
B
C
A
B
C
GC Collected
B
C
C
B
B
C
```

#### Code

```
class TimerExperiment
{
    System.Threading.Timer timerB;

    public TimerExperiment()
    {
        StartTimer("A"); // Not keeping this timer
        timerB = StartTimer("B"); // Keeping this timer
        StartTimer2("C"); // Not keeping this timer
    }

    static System.Threading.Timer StartTimer(string name) {
        return new System.Threading.Timer(_ =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{name}");
        }, null, dueTime: Delay(name), period: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
    }

    static System.Threading.Timer StartTimer2(string name)
    {
        //Create the timer using the constructor which only takes the callback
        var t = new System.Threading.Timer( _ => Console.WriteLine($"{name}"));
        t.Change(dueTime: Delay(name), period: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
        return t;
    }

    static TimeSpan Delay(string name) 
            => TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(Convert.ToInt64(name[0])*10);

}

class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var withTimers = new TimerExperiment();

        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
        GC.Collect();
        Console.WriteLine("GC Collected");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```